# Vertica DB: Need to use a date string and convert as part of where clause

Tags: vertica

I have a field in vertica

```
deviceReceiptTime   -5  Integer 19  8
```

It appears to hold milliseconds

```
1504828819089
1504828819071

Epoch date  Human readable date (GMT) 
1504828819  2017-09-08 00:00:19
```

I would like the analyst to be able to enter a standard date format like 
`YYYY-MMDD HH24MISS` instead of converting to milliseconds first.

instead of

```
where deviceReceiptTime Between 1490270439780 and 1490270448888
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this...

```
where deviceReceiptTime between 
    extract ( epoch from <lower_limit ) and 
    extract ( epoch from <higher_limit> )
```

For example:

```
where deviceReceiptTime between 
    extract ( epoch from '2017-02-08 00:00:00'::timestamp ) and 
    extract ( epoch from '2017-04-08 00:00:00'::timestamp )
```

Comment: I prefer this one to the one before because, here, you convert two constants first, and then compare them to the actual content of the column (which might be indexed), instead of specifying two constants and converting the several million integers to timestamps before comparing them ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_timestamp` function to convert the unix epoch time in UTC (int) to a timestamp value.

```
to_timestamp(receiptTimestamp/1e3) at time zone 'UTC' between '2017-09-15 8:00:00 am' and '2017-09-15 9:00:00 am'
```

The function accepts time in seconds, hence we need to divide by 1000.  You can change the timezone specifier to match your input time zone (i.e.

> at time zone 'America/Chicago's